# Error when I modify number of input channels of inception-v3

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I would like to customize inception_v3 to make it work for 4-channel input.
I tried to modify first layer of inception v3 as below.

```
x=torch.randn((5,4,299,299))

model_ft=models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv=nn.Conv2d(4, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
print(x.shape)
print(model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv)
out=model_ft(x)
```

but it produces the following error.
I think the input shape and  network are correctly modified, so I can't understand why it makes error. does anyone have any advice?

```
torch.Size([5, 4, 299, 299])
Conv2d(4, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)

RuntimeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-41c045338348> in <module>
     29 print(model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv)
     30 
---> 31 out=model_ft(x)
     32 print(out)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py in forward(self, x)
    202     def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> InceptionOutputs:
    203         x = self._transform_input(x)
--> 204         x, aux = self._forward(x)
    205         aux_defined = self.training and self.aux_logits
    206         if torch.jit.is_scripting():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py in _forward(self, x)
    141     def _forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tuple[Tensor, Optional[Tensor]]:
    142         # N x 3 x 299 x 299
--> 143         x = self.Conv2d_1a_3x3(x)
    144         # N x 32 x 149 x 149
    145         x = self.Conv2d_2a_3x3(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/inception.py in forward(self, x)
    474 
    475     def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 476         x = self.conv(x)
    477         x = self.bn(x)
    478         return F.relu(x, inplace=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    441 
    442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 443         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    444 
    445 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    438                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    439         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 440                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    441 
    442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 4, 3, 3], expected input[5, 3, 299, 299] to have 4 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due the param `pretrained=True`.
Since you are using pretrained weights and you cannot edit the shape of pretrained weights to make its adjust for `4 channel`. Hence the error pops up
Plz use it in this way ( which will only load architecture)

```
x=torch.randn((5,4,299,299))
model_ft=models.inception_v3(pretrained=False)
model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv=nn.Conv2d(4, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
print(x.shape)
print(model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv)
out=model_ft(x)
```

and it will work

Comment: But this isn't editing or adjusting the weights, this is replacing the entire layer including the weights. Why isn't that okay? I would understand if you attempted to load a 32x4x3x3 shaped parameter into one with shape 32x3x3x3, but this isn't the case here. first, the  pretrained 32x3x3x3 parameter is loaded into the appropriately shaped conv layer, then that whole layer is replaced with one with 32x4x3x3. also, from the output, it looks like the error was caused by the input having 3 channels instead of 4.

Comment: Unless, does a pretrained model fiddle with the input shape to make it fit what it expects? That's the only way I can make this make sense! Because clearly, x has 4 channels in this case.

Comment: input has 3-channels weights...modeified input has 4 channel weights...so how can one fit 3 channels into 4 channel...unless you have to copy the same weights in 4th dimension as well

Comment: simple question... how can u put 3 balls in 4 holes.. thats what  im trying to say

Comment: Thank you. I found that when I use pretrained inception-v3, the model automatically normalize the input data and the function of the normalization return always 3 channel output. It was why the error occurs. By adding `model_ft.transform_input=False`, I could avoid the error, with pretrained parameters.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback, this makes much more sense to me now. noname, what you say explains everything nicely. @PrajotKuvalekar, I understand the 3 balls in 4 holes scenario, but I don't think that is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when `pretrained=True`, normalization filter for imagenet dataset is applied before the network which can be seen  [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/90a2402b11b58705884b564b7bfce325f1c7d7c7/torchvision/models/inception.py#L45). and the filter is designed for 3 channel input image. It was why the error occurs.

```
def inception_v3(pretrained: bool = False, progress: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> "Inception3":
   ...
    if pretrained:
        if 'transform_input' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['transform_input'] = True
   ...
   return Inception3(**kwargs)


class Inception3(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self,num_classes: int = 1000,aux_logits: bool = True,transform_input: bool = False,inception_blocks: Optional[List[Callable[..., nn.Module]]] = None,init_weights: Optional[bool] = None) -> None:
      super(Inception3, self).__init__()
      ...
      self.transform_input = transform_input
      ...

   def _transform_input(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        if self.transform_input:
            x_ch0 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 0], 1) * (0.229 / 0.5) + (0.485 - 0.5) / 0.5
            x_ch1 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 1], 1) * (0.224 / 0.5) + (0.456 - 0.5) / 0.5
            x_ch2 = torch.unsqueeze(x[:, 2], 1) * (0.225 / 0.5) + (0.406 - 0.5) / 0.5
            x = torch.cat((x_ch0, x_ch1, x_ch2), 1)
        return x
   def forward(self, x: Tensor) -> InceptionOutputs:
        x = self._transform_input(x)
      ...
```

I could finally use pretrained model by the way below.

```
x=torch.randn((5,4,299,299))
model_ft=models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
model_ft.transform_input=False
model_ft.Conv2d_1a_3x3.conv=nn.Conv2d(4, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
out=model_ft(x)
```

Comment: But it is a little bit strange. In other models provided by torchvision (ResNet, VGG etc...) , the transformation is not applied in the model. It is just in Inception, the normalization is automatically applied.